# Форматирование текста send_media_group

Tags: python, telegram, aiogram

Есть бот написанный на aiogram, суть вот в чем. Отправляю медиавложения через метод send_media_group, но не получается добавить мой текст с html тегами. Markdown тоже
пробовал.

```
add_text = '<a href="http://www.example.com/">inline URL</a>'

types.InputMediaPhoto(
       media=messages.photo[length].file_id,
       caption=messages.caption + add_text,
       caption_entities=messages.caption_entities,
)
```

Получаю вот это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Согласно [документации](https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#inputmediaphoto), объект `InputMediaPhoto` принимает параметр `parse_mode`, который Вам нужно установить на HTML:

```py
types.InputMediaPhoto(
       media=messages.photo[length].file_id,
       caption=messages.caption + add_text,
       caption_entities=messages.caption_entities,
       parse_mode=types.ParseMode.HTML
)
```